# How can I generate the vendor folder (with composer) in a docker container and have it available in my host?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, composer-php

I am trying to set up a docker system with 4 services (nginx server, API, MariaDB, frontend). Almost everything is working well, however, for efficiency reasons, I would like to generate the `vendor` folder in the API container, and after that, view this folder in my host. I want to do this because when other people work with these containers, the `vendor` folder should be correctly generated, and I want to avoid things like copying it manually each time someone changes the composer.json... I found a way to do that but this "solution" breaks other things related to the nginx server.

I am going to present two situations because maybe someone knows the solution for one of them:

First of all, my folder structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvVP2.png)

And the nginx.conf which is common for both situations:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass api:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

**Situation 1**: vendor folder is correctly generated in the container but not available in my host.
For this case, adding a volume to link the vendor folders does not work, because doing that the yml creates an empty vendor folder.

backend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY ../backend .

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN composer install -vvv
```

docker/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:  
      - ../backend/src/:/var/www/html/src/
      - ../backend/public/:/var/www/html/public/
    depends_on:
      - server

  frontend:
    image: nginx:1.25-alpine
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: your_root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: your_database_name
      MYSQL_USER: your_database_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: your_database_password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
       
  server:
    image: nginx:1.25-alpine
    container_name: my-nginx-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ../backend/src/:/var/www/html/src/
      - ../backend/public/:/var/www/html/public/
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
    driver: local
```

**Situation 2**: vendor folder is correctly generated in the container and also in the host but nginx returns a 502 bad gateway error.
Here I am adding an entrypoint which wait for the vendor folder, and after that it copies this folder (vendor) to other folder (vendor_host) which is communicated by a volume with my host. This generates correctly the vendor file in the host but Nginx stop working.
This is the error shown in the logs:

```
2023/08/26 16:19:06 [error] 21#21: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.23.0.5:9000", host: "localhost:8000"
```

backend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY ../backend .

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-interaction

COPY ../backend/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

backend/entrypoint.sh

```bash
while [ ! -d "/var/www/html/vendor" ]; do
  sleep 1
done

sleep 15

cp -R /var/www/html/vendor /var/www/html/host_vendor

exec "$@"

tail -f /var/www/html/public/index.php
```

docker/docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: backend/Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    restart: unless-stopped
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    volumes:  
      - ../backend/src/:/var/www/html/src/
      - ../backend/public/:/var/www/html/public/
      # - ../backend/vendor/:/var/www/html/vendor/
      - ../backend/vendor/:/var/www/html/host_vendor/vendor
    depends_on:
      - server

  frontend:
    image: nginx:1.25-alpine
    container_name: frontend
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3001:80
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
       
  server:
    image: nginx:1.25-alpine
    container_name: my-nginx-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ../backend/src/:/var/www/html/src/
      - ../backend/public/:/var/www/html/public/
      - ../backend/vendor/:/var/www/html/host_vendor/vendor
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d

volumes:
  mariadb-data:
    driver: local
```

Thank you

Comment: Is this a Docker problem, a Composer problem, or an nginx problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase depending on the situation, I think first case is a clear Docker problem, and second case is a mixed Docker/Nginx problem. However I do not know which situation is closer to the solution and which steps should I follow to solve them. I would even like  to know some new suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just mount the entire project-root into your containers?

```
server: 
   volumes:
      - ../backend:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

This way your local project is mounted in the container. The only thing you need to explain is that they need to install the project by running `docker-compose exec server composer install`.

You could even add this to the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` scripts instead. So every time the container starts, `composer install` is ran.
Or run it conditionally, for example only if the `vendor` directory doesn't exist.

That way you are sure that the `vendor` directory is "generated" by the image, available on the host and compatible with the php version in the container.

PS: You could also improve on your directory structure a bit. We usually use a `.docker/` directory for docker related configuration inside the project-root. If you have additional requirements for development, create another Dockerfile and change the build context in your docker-compose.yaml. Or add a build argument to your build script so development packages are optional. This will prevent you to create a second Dockerfile, but it's a bit harder to maintain.

For example: only install xdebug if the `_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT` environment variable is set.